# Online gaming lags when WiFi is being used for streaming videos - Updated

Tags: wireless-networking, gaming, wifi-configuration

I have a Coaxial Cable Modem Internet Connection in my home. I like playing online games, specially DoTA2. My computer is connected to my home network via LAN (Ethernet). Everything goes fine, excellent ping, NO LAGS, when I'm the only one using the internet. Everything goes to the crapper whenever my wife or children start using the WIFI on their mobile devices to stream videos from YouTube. I start getting lag spikes and high pings, so my gaming performance is compromised because of this.

My question is, how do I fix it? Is there a possibility that I can allocate a specific bandwidth exclusively for the WiFi, so my online gaming is not affected?

This are the specs of my router.

THis is the main menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT41N.png

And this are the  manufacturer and model and the only options resembling QoS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFGbQ.png

I have and old Wireless Swith from TPLINK, model TLWR841ND.

Comment: Get yourself a router which has firmware that supports QOS, connect all devices to the router, then configure your QOS so that every other client is a lower priority than your device.

Comment: And/or upgrade your Internet package to one with more bandwidth... If you have plenty then @Ramhound has the best answer. BTW, including details about your current service, router, WiFi equipment, etc could be helpful... The devil is on the details.

Comment: @acejavelin - Upgrading the package for more bandwidth will just cause YouTube to eat more bandwidth in all likelyhood

Comment: @ramhound QoS is an attempt to work around the symptoms. Smart Queueing (CoDel) actually fixes the root cause bug (which is bufferbloat).

Comment: @Ramhound Guess I have not seen that... I have a 100/15Mbps connection, and have conglomeration of consoles, PCs, Roku devices, smartphones, etc. all connected and working simultaneously on an Asus RT-N66U router with no QoS in place, viewing multiple video streams and online gaming from multiple devices at the same time has zero lag issues, but when I had a 25/4 connection it lagged bad with multiple things going on.

Comment: @acejavelin If your middleboxes have bufferbloat bugs, congestion will cause lag. The best solution is to fix bufferbloat. But as you said, you can work around the bug by getting a faster connection that's less likely to become congested. Also, as Ramhound said, you can work around the bug by using QoS to force less-lag-sensitive traffic (like large downloads and well-buffered video streams) to bear the brunt of it. But the real solution is to fix the bufferbloat bug.

Answer (score 1):

Those are classic symptoms of a common router bug known as bufferbloat. One way to address it is to install an open source firmware distro such as DD-WRT or OpenWrt on your router and enable the CoDel or FQ-CoDel smart queueing algorithm, which was developed specifically to fix this bug. Sometimes it helps to also enable traffic shaping to make your router a slight bottleneck, so that CoDel can work its magic on your network even if the box running CoDel is not the only one where long buffer queues had been building up.

For an off-the-shelf solution, look at IQrouter.